# Javascript function on keypress?

Tags: javascript, events, keypress

I've been searching SO and the remaining internet, and I can't find a straight answer anywhere. How might someone execute javascript function `aFunction` when key `m` is pressed and released while no element (text box, etc) is focused?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/)

```
$('body').keypress(function(e){
  if(e.which == 109)
    aFunction();
})
```

Here is a [demo on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lechevalierd3on/J9PAW/)

Edit: lowercase m is 109

Comment: Just try it yourself `$("body").keypress(function(e){console.log(e.which)});`

Comment: @30n This just isn't working... I have linked jquery, and I have a <script /> with the code you gave me, and I've tried many keys, while nothing else is selected. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Typing on azerty on a qwerty keyboard I got missed up sorry.

Comment: @lucase.62 I guess you can close the question.